# netlify deploy fails with error [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import

Tags: deployment, svelte, netlify, rollup, vite

Deploying to netlify fails with error: `[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import...`, but it works when I build locally using `npm run build` (same as netlify). The package that fails to resolve is installed directly from github, as opposed to the other packages.

package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.2",
        "focus-visible": "^5.2.0",
        "just-throttle": "^4.0.1",
        "lrud": "github:bbc/lrud#master",
        "sapper-environment": "^1.0.1"
    }
```

netlify logs:

```
10:10:48 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:10:48 PM:   1. build.command from netlify.toml                            
10:10:48 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:10:48 PM: ​
10:10:48 PM: $ npm run build
10:10:48 PM: > sveltekit-movie-app@0.0.1 build
10:10:48 PM: > svelte-kit build
10:10:49 PM: vite v2.7.10 building for production...
10:10:49 PM: transforming...
10:10:52 PM: ✓ 54 modules transformed.
10:10:52 PM: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "Lrud" from "src/lib/stores/keyNavigation.ts".
10:10:52 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
10:10:52 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
10:10:52 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`
```

keyNavigation.ts:

```
import { Lrud } from 'Lrud';
```

Why does deployment fail at netlify, but not locally?

Answer (score 5):

The LRUD documentation says

```
const { Lrud } = require('Lrud')
```

and the following works locally:

```
import { Lrud } from 'Lrud';
```

That is probably because the Mac environment doesn't care about upper/lower case in file references in this context. However, on Netlify it makes a difference. Changing the import statement to the following  made the Netlify deployment pass:

```
import { Lrud } from 'lrud';
```